# Socket.IO support for Blackberry

Tags: javascript, blackberry, socket.io

Does [Socket.IO](http://socket.io/) support BlackBerry OS 6 or later?

Comment: What "Socket.IO" are you referring to?  Please be more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works on BB 6 and BB 7 simulators though the website did not [mention](http://socket.io/#browser-support) BlackBerry last time I checked.

BB 5 and BB 4.7 did not work, at least not with my demo app which depended on jQuery 1.7.2.